# Unable to import estimation module in lifetimes

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, lifetimes-python

I'm trying to analyze customer shopping data and I'm trying this using lifetimes package in Python.I'm unable to import estimation module in lifetime

```
from lifetimes.utils import *
from lifetimes.plotting import *

from lifetimes.estimation import *

from lifetimes.estimation import *
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lifetimes.estimation'

Answer (score 1):

install lifetimes version 0.2.2.2

https://pypi.org/project/Lifetimes/0.2.2.2/

```
pip install Lifetimes==0.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought to expand on it a bit more in case anyone else faces the same issue (due to following redundant codes).

The lifetimes.estimation module is no longer available within the lifetimes package (as per the [latest model documentation](https://lifetimes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#lifetimes-estimation-module)). All the functionalities in this module were moved to other modules and you really do not need this module anymore. Continue using the latest model version 0.11.1 and don't import this specific submodule.